# google app engine search api raising error: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Query found

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using google app engine search API and doing a simple search like

```
options = search.QueryOptions(
                limit=200,
                cursor=cursor,
                returned_fields=['my_id', 'file_key']
            )


query = search.Query(query_string="new OR old", options=options)
```

but i am getting this error:
    TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Query found

if i remove the "OR" condition from the query string or the returned field options the error is removed.

Comment: You should include a stack trace.

Comment: could you tell us exactly what query_string worked.

Comment: query_string = "new" and query string = "old" worked